# React context keep resetting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-context, react-state

I have this file that contains all of my global routing / global state.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';



const globalState = {
  email: null,
  token: null
};

export const  AuthContext = React.createContext(globalState);

function Routing() {

  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(globalState);
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={[currentUser, setCurrentUser]}>

      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Routing />, document.getElementById("app"));      
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

The thing is when I try to log out with this function the global state changes for about 3 seconds and it resets again."The user gets logged in again automatically".

```
const [user, setUser] = useContext(AuthContext);

const logOut = () => {
    setUser({email: null, token:null})

  }
```

I tried to look if there is any special way to change the global context but I didn't find anything.

How to stop the re-login "re-change of the state" of the AuthContext "Global state"

Here is my login

```
const login = e => {
    const form = document.getElementById('loginForm');
    e.preventDefault();
      setInterval(() => {
        setUser({email, token});
      }, timeOut);
    })
 }
```

Comment: Why the `setInterval(() => {` at **exactly 3 seconds**? Did you not suspect that to log you in again?

Comment: I meant to type: set timeout thanks a lot
are you available for mentoring?

Comment: yes, you can send me an email

Comment: As I said on your Facebook post and implicitly suggested by @HMR in his answer, removing irrelevant code may be of great help. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not demonstrate what you describe, here is your code and I don't see it logging out magically after 3 seconds so you must have done something wrong somewhere else:

```js
const { useState, useContext } = React;

const globalState = {
  email: null,
  token: null,
};

const AuthContext = React.createContext(globalState);
const LoginOut = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useContext(AuthContext);

  const logOut = () => {
    setUser({ email: null, token: null });
  };
  const login = () => {
    setUser({ email: 'hi', token: 123 });
  };
  return user.email ? (
    <button onClick={logOut}>log out {user.email}</button>
  ) : (
    <button onClick={login}>log in</button>
  );
};
function Routing() {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(
    globalState
  );
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={[currentUser, setCurrentUser]}
    >
      <LoginOut />
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Routing />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I added my login function